# Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Tags: pascal

I have a project that I'm going to rewrite to another language, and in order to do that - I'd like to build it. But when I try to build it, I receive "E1012: Constant expression violates subrange bounds".

I have such code:

```
var ForTolkResult : array[0..2000] of char;

    ForTolkResult[sizeof(ForTolkResult)-1] := chr(0); // Occurs here
```

From my point of view everything is correct here, `sizeof(ForTolkResult) = 2000 * 1`, so `sizeof(ForTolkResult) - 1 = 1999`, that is in bounds of an array. (But I'm new to Pascal) So what's wrong here?

I'm trying to build it via Embarcadero C++ Builder. If this error is a bug in compiler, how can I turn this check off?

Comment: `var ForTolkResult : array[0..2000] of char;` 
by the way this array has 2001 elements

Comment: Ok, if 2000 is included - still the same logic applies. sizeof(F) - 1 = 2000 that is in bounds of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does char really ocuppy one byte of memory? I mean, check whether it is an "Ansi" single-byte char and not a WideChar.

Anyway, when you need to access the last index of an array, you'd better use

```
ForTolkResult[High(ForTolkResult)] := chr(0);
```

Comment: I'm not so convenient in Pascal, but the only thing I need is being able to run it. Changing sizeof to High helped, so thanks! It still doesn't build so I will try to address the developers who developed that. Thanks!